# How to define Siddhi time window for complete current day

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

What is the syntax for writing Siddhi time window expression for current day only. I want to calculate number of events group by any event attribute for today's date only. 
I am planning to use #window.time(86400000) but assume that CEP server started at mid of the day than this time period may fall into next day, which is against my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not currently supported out of the box in Siddhi. You will need to write a custom extension for a Time Window to achieve this. You can refer to the Siddhi documentation at [1] to learn more about writing a custom window processor for Siddhi.

[1] https://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Writing+a+Custom+Window